# Sending mail without smtp server and credentials in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sendmail, smtpclient

I have a contact us form in one of my asp.net website, which contains following field:

1. Name
2. Contact Number
3. Email Address
4. Subject
5. Message

Now whenever user fill up the form and submit it, i want to receive mail in my inbox with the user's mail as the "from".

Now as i don't know which server user would be using and his credentials, how can i send the mail, "from" as his email address and "to" as mine.

I know that's quite possible, [here is one of the site who does exactly that](http://www.123greetings.com)

Once you choose any of the greetings and click on send, it will ask you for sender's name and email and receiver's name and email and it sends email to receiver with the senders mail in the from field.

Comment: So are you confused as to which .NET objects and properties to use to send the mail within your code?

Comment: NO @Karl, i want that whenever user fill out form and send, i will receive the mail in my gmail inbox, but the mail's FROM should be the email id which user has filled in the contact form. Hope i am clear from my end, let me know if its still not clear

Comment: Do you have the code for your form when the user clicks 'Submit'?

Comment: i know sending normal mails, but for the above feature, i could not find the logic.

Answer (score 1):

SmtpClient uses MailMessage to send emails. MailMessage has From property. See the link, it has code example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.from.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this overkill for what you want to do, but I have used this in the past with great results, especially with sending both text and HTML versions of email.

[Open Source .NET e-Mail Templating Engine](http://thecodedecanter.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/town-crier-an-open-source-e-mail-templating-engine-for-net/)